# Working with multiple iOS Developer accounts

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning

Here's the scenario: Our company recently bought an Enterprise Developer Account. We already have a standard Developer Account.

Now when I try to do an archive build i get the message:

```
Certificate identity 'iPhone Distribution: <Company Name>' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one.
```

Neither by using automatic profile selector nor by explicitly setting the correct profile I get the app signed. Both certificates have identical names, could that be the problem?

Is there any way of dealing with multiple certificates without having to temporarily delete the keys from the keychain (which, as many of you may know, doesn't work that well since these keys "magically" reappear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different company names to differentiate between Enterprise and Commercial/Standard, otherwise you'll get naming conflicts.

More info on how: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html

Comment: Just FYI: A quick mail to Apple Dev Support, a really fast response and our Enterprise account now has a new name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if your apple account contains more than one distribution certificate or not. If it contains more than one, then remove the unnecessary one and make it contain only a single distribution certificate.

- Remove old certificate from keychain which is duplicate.
- Now go to the xcode organizer and from there remove provisioning profiles which are created using removed certificate OR old certificate.
- Install new certificate and provisioning profile if not installed.
- Make sure apple account contain single distribution certificate and  newly created provisioning profile point to the certificate which you left to remove in apple account.

Now be happy!!!, Issue:"Certificate identity 'iPhone Distribution: ' appears more than once in the keychain" may resolve.